# Vue:@click dynamic blinding params error

Tags: html, vue.js

I wrote a page including a v-for bindinds like this:

```
<tr v-for = "goods in goodsList">
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="beginsale(goods.goods_id)" v-if="searchData.GOODS_SE_STATUS == 'INSTOCK'">上架</button>
```

The question is that:

When I firstly click the button who bling the "beginsale" function, it works well with the corrret params(goods_id a eg:850)

But when I clicked another one it passed the same params to the function "beginsale"(850 in this example).

It should pass a new params to the function in my design but failed anywhere.
have no ideas on this..

Comment: are you sure the `goodsList` data has different good_id values?

Comment: yeah im sure, cause if I refresh my page everytime I clicked this button, it works well and others text goes on well

Comment: the problem must be either in the "goodsList" data or in the `beginsale()` function. Can you edit your post and share them?